# Converting promise based code to async await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

My testcase code looks like this-

```
it("should do something", function(done) {
  function1("someparam").then(() => {
   function2("someparam").then(() => {
    functionN("someparam").then(() => {
      comp(expectedfile,0.001,actualfile, done);
    });
  });
});
```

I want to use async await to make this more readable and avoid all this nesting. Can someone help me understand how to do it?

Regards
+Ad

Comment: Do function1, function2 and functionN return a promise? If not, then you are using promises in the wrong way.

Comment: Yes, these functions return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
 it("should do something", async function (done) {

       let temp = await function1("someparam");

       let temp2 = await function2("someparam");

       let temp3 = await function2("someparam");

       let temp4 = await comp(expectedfile, 0.001, actualfile, done);
 });
```

Where you will get Promise value (Either Reject, Resolved or Error) and you can pass it in next call as per your requirements.